# Creating an online visual designer using silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, designer

I'm trying to create an visual designer like Visual Studio, Expression Blend, Dreamweaver etc as an **ONLINE APPLICATION** (ASP.NET).

Can Silverlight be helpful with this? 
What are the things i need to be aware of before starting developing this online app?
How good is it dragging, dropping & moving controls around with Silverlight?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good at everything you asked for. Draggable, Dockable, etc, all these controls exists in open source and commercial libraries.

Check out telerik controls, they once had a demo that simulated visual studio's IDE. If telerik can build controls like these, then so can you (either from scratch or modifying free controls).

Comment: Can you help me find that link for Telerik Demo? I'm trying to find it.

Comment: I'll look later. But just so you know, it was a 2009 demo.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight could be helpful, as it brings (to a certain extent) the desktop paradigm to web applications.

Silverlight certainly supports drag and drop and with the `Canvas` element you have the basis for your visual designer's workspace.

This will be a large undertaking and it would be worth breaking it down into smaller pieces that you can develop one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check out the drag-n-drop and canvas stuffs.